# User defined conversion assigned to const ref variable via temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11

The code below is a simplified version of the actual problem I am facing.

Assume I do not have permission to modify **class A** (as it is external library), and its already widely used in my existing code base.

The const & assignment from a temporary object (direct constructor) which also return a const & member variable via implicit conversion is not valid in this case.

How do I prevent or make it legal in this case so that the caller gets the correct **A** value?

```
class A 
{
public:
    A() {  }
    A(int _r, int _g, int _b)
        : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b)
    {
    }

    ~A(){ }

    int GetR() const {  return r; }
    int GetG() const { return g; }
    int GetB() const { return b; }

private:
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : Foo(A()) {}
    Foo(int _r, int _g, int _b) : a(A(_r, _g, _b)) {}
    explicit Foo(const A& _a) : a(_a) {}

    Foo& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        *this = Foo(a);
        return *this;
    }

    operator A() const { return a; }
    operator const A&() const {  return a; }

private:
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    const A& a = Foo(200, 100, 300); 
    std::cout << a.GetR() << a.GetG() << a.GetB() << endl; // I may not get 200 100 300 here as Foo is already out of scope 

    return 0;
}
```

**Motivation**

Some background on why I am implementing a class as above. The actual purpose of class **Foo** is to contain 2 different objects, which actually has the same purpose, just different way of storing data internally. For example, let's say **class A** and **class B**, which stores RGB value of color in int and floating (normalized) respectively. And as mentioned above, I do not have permission to modify class A, and its already widely used in my code base.

There are tons of function in my code base which takes in `const A&` and `const B&` as a function param. So I am trying to unify this 2 classes for a particular case, where I can just pass in `Foo` in those places and it will work as expected.

Comment: Just don't do invalid stuff like `const A& a = Foo(200, 100, 300);`? However, doing something like `some_function_taking_a_const_ref_to_A(Foo(...))` will actually work, since the temporary `Foo` object will exist until the end of the full expression (i.e. until the function returns).

Comment: On another note, if the real `A` is as simple as shown in the question, then perhaps inherit it instead, making `Foo` an `A`?

Comment: Why two conversion operator? Just the 1st one would be fine.

Comment: @songyuanyao, because the first one will create copy which I do not want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I did initially. But there will be another problem. In actual use, class Foo contains 2 objects ( I have explained this in the motivation). So the second objects value will be cached. So now lets say someone take modify class A via its setter method, or even worse, take a reference to class A and then modify it, I have no way to control it

Comment: Something like `A const &a = static_cast<A>(Foo(1, 2, 3));`?

Comment: @bipll, This suggestion is to enforce the caller to do the right thing. Is there any way I fix it on my class to prevent such wrong usage?

Comment: @sivan The caller must always do the right thing. What is the purpose of taking a reference to a member variable of a temporary? Why not keep the `Foo` instance for as long as you need one of its members? `Foo f(200, 100, 300); const A& a = f;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo fair point. I do agree that caller should be aware. But I just think my introduction of type-cast operator will be often overlooked, and make the caller do such mistake. Which is why I am trying to control it from my class

Comment: Ok. I don't think you can (without making a copy of `A`) but you could bind directly to the member variable if you make it `public`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/j4q96dMh5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [ref-qualified member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions) (since C++11), i.e. mark the conversion operator with lvalue-reference, to prevent it being called on temporaries (rvalues).

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ... ...

    operator A() const { return a; }
    operator const A&() const & {  return a; }
    operator const A&() && = delete;

    ... ...
};
```

Then

```
const A& a = Foo(200, 100, 300);                 // invalid; invokes deleted operator
const A& a = static_cast<A>(Foo(200, 100, 300)); // fine; invokes operator A()
```

Comment: That works! However, I won't need the first one right? That prevents me from doing a valid copy assignment like this ```Foo f(90, 90, 90); A a = f;```

Comment: @sivan Instead of `const A& a = static_cast<A>(Foo(200, 100, 300));` you could do `const A a = Foo(200, 100, 300);` in this case - it's a copy of `Foo::a` in both versions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually no, it will give compilation error because assignment of ```Foo(200, 100, 300)``` directly to a variable is a r-value operator which we have deleted. But I am ok with it, as long as improper usage is flagged by compiler and require users attention to fix it

Comment: @songyuanyao, Actually with first and second operator, I still will not be able to assign ```static_cast<A>(Foo(200, 100, 300))``` as it is ambiguous between the first 2 operators. But thats fine with me. I can introduce a function that returns copy of value for such cases.

Comment: @sivan Yes, with the 2 overload we can't avoid such ambiguity, you have to specify the converted type explicitly like `Foo f(90, 90, 90); A a3 = static_cast<const A&>(f);`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thank you. I am accepting this as an answer